# spring security redirect page login

Tags: java, spring

I do not have any exceptions or errors, but there is a redirect loop on one of the pages.
And after login go the pages directory and your index web page in this directory

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="phonecashAuthenticationManager">
    <form-login login-page='/signin*' login-processing-url="/pages/client/phonecash_security_signin"
                authentication-failure-url="/signin.faces?failed=true"
                default-target-url="/pages/client/index.faces"/>

<intercept-url pattern="/pages/agentpanel/**" access="hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_AGENT,ROLE_AGENT_MERCHANT,ROLE_AGENT_LICENSEE,ROLE_AGENT_MERCHANT_LICENSEE,PRIVILEGE_WEB_GENERAL)" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/merchantpanel/**" access="hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_MERCHANT,ROLE_AGENT_MERCHANT,ROLE_MERCHANT_LICENSEE,ROLE_AGENT_MERCHANT_LICENSEE,PRIVILEGE_WEB_GENERAL)" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/licenseepanel/**" access="hasAnyAuthority(ROLE_LICENSEE,ROLE_AGENT_LICENSEE,ROLE_MERCHANT_LICENSEE,ROLE_AGENT_MERCHANT_LICENSEE,PRIVILEGE_WEB_GENERAL)" />
</http>
```

spring security redirect loop infinite to login page

Comment: Post spring security config.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your intercept-url

```
   <intercept-url pattern="/pages/client/index.faces" />
```